# Workflow Action Failed to Trigger Flow

Tags: process-builder

I am getting the following error message:

```
Workflow Action Failed to Trigger Flow
The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version IDxxxxxx
```

I would like to investigate which process causes the error, but have no idea how to find the correct process, as only the ID is given.

How can I find out?
Tia, Lily

Comment: Please check any active process builder. Process builder is main issue here.

Comment: If you use the Id in the Salesforce URL line as https://<nodeid>.Salesforce.com/<processid> that should take you to the specific process.

Comment: Capture debug logs, wherein you can set debug log level for Workflow as Finest, to capture the error in the logs and then perform the action which is causing issue, it will give you all the details why it is failing.